# How to indicate desire to remain local on resume

Tags: resume, relocation

I've seen several questions regarding wanting to relocate, including [this one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/38876/45671), and [this one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/13144/45671), but my issue is that I am unable, and have no desire, to relocate. I indicate this on my profile on various job boards, when it's available, but I still get inquiries about my availability for positions nowhere near where I live. Is there an acceptable way of indicating this on my resume?

This is different from the linked questions, as I am not submitting a resume and cover letter to jobs out of my area, I'm just posting it on job boards.

Comment: The answers given to the questions you linked also answer your question. Don't put that in the resume, put it in the cover letter.

Comment: I'm not submitting a resume and cover letter to any jobs, I'm just posting my resume on job boards.

Comment: People read your note on the profile, they ignore it and call you anyway. There is not much you can do about it. Putting it on the resume won't help much there.

Comment: @MaskedMan  People don't read anything, bots scrape your profile and spam you on behalf of people; and since the initial step is done by software there's no reason to try and filter out people who won't fit.  It's much less work (for the bot writer) to just let the recipient say "nope" and delete the message.

Comment: @DanNeely Yeah, there's that too, and you are right, that is a lot more common than humans reading the profile. So overall, it looks like if the OP writing about his location preference in the profile doesn't matter, putting it in the resume won't make any difference either.

Comment: Heh, this may or may not be a good solution for you, but why not take a page from posting personals :D? Something like "Local inquiries only" at the very bottom? Or at the very top if it's that important to you. And if you're able to add text about your resume, I would put it in the text box meaning I would try to avoid putting this on my actual resume as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason why you can't put "looking for opportunities in the x area" on your post, and it may help, but will it stop the others? No

I lived in the UK for many years, in Scotland. I would get recruiters approach me for jobs in the South of England (other side of the country).

I moved back to Canada, and despite "reminding" agencies I am no longer in their market, they still approach me with UK jobs.

Why? Well the recruiter has two objectives.  If you aren't interested they hope you'll be able to recommend someone to save them doing their job.

So it won't stop, but being may make a recruiter who has a relevant job approach you even if you aren't everything he wants, especially if the place you want to be is less easy to recruit into, so no harm in trying.